# Trying to insert new field into each object within an array using TS

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular project where I have a block of code that returns an array of objects, which consists of contact records.

I have a 'forEach' loop where I create a new field with the user's initials.

I want to then push this new field 'userInitials' into the appropriate record.

I have the following code, but it's pushing new objects and not new fields, but when I remove the object brackets, I get errors.

```
    let initialHold: any;
    let contactWithInitials = [];

    this.contacts.forEach( eachObj => {
      if(eachObj.first_name){
        initialHold = eachObj.first_name.charAt(0);
      }
      if(eachObj.last_name){
        initialHold += eachObj.last_name.charAt(0);
      }

      this.contacts.push({'userInitials':initialHold});

    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this `eachObj['userInitials'] = initialHold` instead of `this.contacts.push({'userInitials':initialHold});`. You want to mutate the original object, then you have to add the new property to the `eachObj` once you create the new property.